# Separate activation from a timedistributed layer

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I implemented a model with several consecutive TimeDistributed layers. My last layer is defined as followed :

```
y_pred = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim, name="y_pred", kernel_initializer=init, bias_initializer=init, activation="softmax"), name="out")(x)
```

I would like to remove the activation "softmax" of the latter to access its logits i.e :

```
logit = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_dim, name="fc6", kernel_initializer=init, bias_initializer=init), name="logit")(x)
```

If I want to get back the initial y_pred, I wrote :

```
(1) y_pred = TimeDistributed(Activation('softmax'), name="pred")(logit)
```

I'm confused because the following line seems to work also :

```
(2) y_pred = Activation('softmax', name="pred")(logit)
```

Which one is correct ? (1) or (2) ?
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually follows the same semantics as by default `Activation('softmax')` applies the activation to last `axis=-1`. It is the [default argument](https://keras.io/activations/#softmax). So even if you use `TimeDistributed` you are applying it to the last dimension but the latter without distribution would be faster as it involves less operations.